# How to install bc on a unix system under local environment

Tags: bc

I am trying ti install bc on my cluster.
I used

```
./configure --prefix=/home/astha/soft/bc-1.07
```

followed by

```
make
```

but getting below error while executing make

```
./fbc -c ./libmath.b </dev/null >libmath.h
./fix-libmath_h
./fix-libmath_h: line 1: ed: command not found
make[2]: *** [libmath.h] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/astha/soft/bc-1.07/bc'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/astha/soft/bc-1.07'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Is there any workaround for it?

Comment: Looks like your missing `ed` - which is odd considering Linux usually comes with it. Install it or change the line using it to do the same thing with tools you have (probably changing the prefix in some file).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same snag building under MingW32.  fix-libmath_h is a fairly simple here document for ed.  I was able to edit libmath.h using vim and rerun make.

You can pretty much hit ":" and type each line into vim.  You don't need to escape the "$" in vim.

If you are not familiar with ed, the script basically deletes the last line, puts all the lines in quotes with a trailing comma and adds a leading brace to the first line and trailing zero and a closing brace to the last line.